# Spellcheck on SE sites

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign

This is really more of a request, but would it be possible to implement a simple spell-check when asking / answering questions, excluding constructions within MathJax environment? I think it may cut down on number of the minor reviews necessary, help non-English speakers, and dyslexic people, as well as helping people who type carelessly (like me unfortunately!) - especially for long Q/A? Sloppy spelling often gets in the way of the key message of the question, which of course is the main point of SE. It would be nice if such a feature existed, with option to turn off if desired.

Comment: I am going to decline this as [tag:status-bydesign] because, as you noted, this is more an issue with the browser rather than something we would implement on this system specifically.

Comment: @RobertCartaino sure - I just voted to close too, rather than delete as I think halirutan's answer & Mr.Wizard's comments are a useful ref. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, actually spell-check should work inside your browser. It would be counterproductive to include it to SE because there are sites that are multilingual (like German-Language SE). Why don't you just turn it on inside your browser, then you probably see your that you misspelled "implement" :D

> [image]

Comment: ah, so this is a browser issue rather than an SE one. I use Firefox, and have schecked options though couldn't find anything :/

Comment: @martin Look at [this here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-do-i-use-firefox-spell-checker). That should help you with FF.

Comment: that is strange - it is turned on already :/

Comment: thanks for pointing out "implement" BTW!!!

Comment: Hmm, that's indeed strange. I use Chrome and cannot really help you, but I'm relying on spell check very much too.

Comment: I'll look into it - may haver to reset FF or something ...

Comment: @martin If you right-click in editor field is **Check Spelling** tickmarked within the context menu that comes up?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard If you mean in _Mathematica_ SE, no, it isn't (I'm not sure I get a context menu). If you mean in Firefox, I can't see a context menu ...

Comment: @martin I mean in Firefox.  Nothing happens when you right-click within the editor area?  You should see something like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/e2kcb.png

Comment: @Mr.Wizard no - just cut, copy, etc + Inspect Element. Do I need another addon or something?

Comment: @martin As far as I can recall it should be built-in.  Please type `about:config` into the location bar and press return.  (Accept "I'll be careful" or whatever warning it is if you get one.)  Then type `layout.spell` in the **Search** field.  You should see an item `layout.spellcheckDefault` -- what is the **Value** set to?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard it is set to 1

Comment: @martin Try setting it to `2` and see if anything changes.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard no, set it to 2, then restarted FF, still nothing :(

Comment: @martin Sorry, I'm out of ideas.  I suggest you take this to a Firefox forum, or perhaps SuperUser.

Comment: @MrWizard - that's a good idea, thanks :) ... Or I could try & type more carefully!!!